# Troubleshooting playing of audio files in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am experiencing crashing and not playing of my audio files in pygame. I get this error when trying to trigger my audio file:  RESTART: /Users/matthewmacy/Desktop/WORKING platupdate PROJECT_HELPED/main.py 
SELFTRACKS!!! 4 In my code I generate a random number between 1 and 5 (self.tracks = random.randint(1,5)) which is suppose to determine the track played at random. I can successfully play a track for the initial splash screen but then the subsequent game music does not play. I thought a potential problem might be that I am cutting the splash screen audio when I am turning on the game audio. I thought that having a timer to start the music after 5 seconds would make for enough time between audio start/stop. If anyone know a fix for this please fill me in.

```
 def show_start_screen(self):
    # game splash/start screen

    pg.mixer.music.load('beautiful_reverb.wav')
    pg.mixer.music.play(-1)

    bg = pg.image.load("1366X768EDITEDflag.png")
    self.screen.blit(bg,(0,0))


    pg.display.flip()
    self.wait_for_key()

    #Go to controls Screen and cut music when clicked
    controls = pg.image.load("1366X768ControlsFINAL.png")
    self.screen.blit(controls,(0,0))
    pg.display.flip()
    self.wait_for_key()
    pg.mixer.music.stop()


    self.PlayMusic()


def PlayMusic(self):

    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update3 > 5000:
        self.last_update3 = now
        self.tracks = random.randint(1,5)
        print("SELFTRACKS!!!", self.tracks)
        if self.tracks == 1:
            pg.mixer.music.load('1GOODPARTS1.wav')
            pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
        if self.tracks == 2:
            pg.mixer.music.load('2FminorScale.wav')
            pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
        if self.tracks == 3:
            pg.mixer.music.load('3GOODfunnyTRumpdance3.wav')
            pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
        if self.tracks == 4:
            pg.mixer.music.load('4GOODfunnyTrumpdance4.wav')
            pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
        if self.tracks == 5:
            pg.mixer.music.load('5OLDschoolVideogame.wav')
            pg.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [tutorial](http://www.nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part3). Especially the 'Doing Something When a Song Ends:' paragraph is interesting for you. Define an event type, call `pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)` and in the event loop just check if this event was in the event queue, pick a random song and play it.

```
import sys
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

SONGS = ['song1.wav', 'song2.wav', 'song3.wav']
# Here we create a custom event type (it's just an int).
SONG_END = pg.USEREVENT + 1
# When a song is finished, pygame will add the
# SONG_END event to the event queue.
pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)
# Load and play the first song.
pg.mixer.music.load('song1.wav')
pg.mixer.music.play(0)


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            # If the SONG_END event gets emitted, just
            # pick a random song and play it.
            if event.type == SONG_END:
                print('The song ended. Playing random song.')
                pg.mixer.music.load(random.choice(SONGS))
                pg.mixer.music.play(0)

        screen.fill((30, 60, 80))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: This answer just shows a better alternative to choose random songs and switch them. I can't tell why the game crashes without more context.

Comment: One thing that I can already say is that, if the user clicks before 5 seconds have passed, the `if now - self.last_update3 > 5000:` check prevents that a new track can be chosen and played. Just remove it.

Comment: When i use my audio with the above tutorial I still crash. I don't know what is the problem!

Comment: I remove the timer and I still get crashing! My audio isn't particularly long so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I still have your complete project that you sent me some days ago. It works correctly for me (after removing the timer), so you probably have introduced an error elsewhere. Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: There is no traceback it just crashes. Only the first song is able to play so I can't help but think its something to do with the files I am playing.

Comment: it says:>>> RESTART: /Users/matthewmacy/Desktop/WORKING platupdate PROJECT_HELPED/main.py 
SELFTRACKS!!! 3 and also: RESTART: /Users/matthewmacy/Desktop/WORKING platupdate PROJECT_HELPED/main.py 
SELFTRACKS!!! 4

Comment: OK, I've got no idea why that happens or what it means. Are all of the audio files in the right directory and do they work correctly outside of pygame?

Comment: In the tracks that are not working I noticed I had color coded them. I removed the color coding and the program still crashes. I don't know why this is happening. They are in the same directory as the main.py file. They are relatively short tracks.

Comment: I reduce the randomize function to a def PlayMusic(self): pg.mixer.music.load('5OLDschoolVideogame.wav')
               pg.mixer.music.play(-1) and the program still crashes. IDLE doesn't like the files for some reason. IS there a preferred file format other than wav?

Comment: I export the audio again in Logic and the file still crashes the program.

Comment: I think .ogg files work fine in pygame, but I haven't had problems with .wav either. I've only heard that .mp3 can cause trouble.

Comment: I tried an ogg file and it gave an error saying unrecognized format will try again,

Comment: The program works. I would like to still add breaks between music play and have the tracks not repeat. Any ideas?

Comment: Do anything like in the program in my answer? To add a short pause, maybe you could add a short track without sound.